# MATLAB union WITH repetitions

Tags: matlab, union

I'm having trouble with the `union` function. I'm trying to index trading days and calendar days so I can make calculations. What I want is a union *with* repetitions. Is there another way to do this?

```
tradeDates=tradeDates(:,1); % grab trading days
calDays=datetime([2008,08,25])+caldays(0:2522)'; % grab calendar days
calDays=yyyymmdd(calDays); % convert to yyymmdd format
[C,ia,ib]=union(tradeDates,calDays); % set intersection of arrays
```

Comment: Problem is not replicable. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Comment: Give a small example with inputs and desired output

Comment: The idea of `union` is to avoid repetitions, if you don't want this, don't use `union`. What you seem to want is just simple concatenating and sorting, something like `sort( [tradeDates(:);calDays(:)] )`